# How to get the Date of the first day of a week given a time stamp in Hadoop Hive?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hiveql, dayofweek

Besides writing a custom UDF to support this issue, is there any known methods of achieving this? I'm currently using Hive 0.13.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Hive 1.2, you can also do it like this:

```
select next_day(date_sub('2019-01-01', 7), 'MON')
```

Output:

```
2018-12-31
```

Answer (score 4):

`date_sub(m.invitationdate,pmod(datediff(m.invitationdate,'1900-01-07'),7))`

This expression gives the exact solution to my question.

Regards,

Boris

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest and the best solution for fetching 1st day of the week's date:

For Current timstamp:

```
select date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u') AS int)) ;
```

For any given date or column:

```
select date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-05-15','yyyy-MM-dd')), cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-05-15','yyyy-MM-dd'), 'u') AS int)) ;

select date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(colname,'yyyy-MM-dd')), cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(colname,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'u') AS int)) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this without writing a UDF.  If you look at at the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) under datetime functions, there is a function `from_unixtime()` that takes a unix timestamp and a string pattern.  A couple of functions down on the documentation page, there is a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) that explains the different patterns you can use in this function.  So, from your timestamp, you can extract the day of the week and proceed accordingly.

**Example Data**:

```
1445313193
1445313100
1445313146
1445040000
1445040023
1445040111
```

The first three are Monday, 2015-10-19 and the last three are Friday, 2015-10-16.

**Query**:

```
select day_of_week
  , date_var
  , case when day_of_week = 'Sun' then date_var
    when day_of_week = 'Sat' then date_sub(date_var, 6)
    when day_of_week = 'Fri' then date_sub(date_var, 5)
    when day_of_week = 'Thu' then date_sub(date_var, 4)
    when day_of_week = 'Wed' then date_sub(date_var, 3)
    when day_of_week = 'Tue' then date_sub(date_var, 2)
    when day_of_week = 'Mon' then date_sub(date_var, 1)
    else NULL
    end as first_day_of_week_date
from (
  select from_unixtime(timestamp, 'EEE') day_of_week
    , from_unixtime(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd') date_var
  from db.table ) A
```

**Output**:

```
Mon 2015-10-19  2015-10-18
Mon 2015-10-19  2015-10-18
Mon 2015-10-19  2015-10-18
Fri 2015-10-16  2015-10-11
Fri 2015-10-16  2015-10-11
Fri 2015-10-16  2015-10-11
```

So, for today it returns yesterday, which was Sunday, and for last Friday, it returns the previous Sunday, the 11th.  I am making the assumption that by "first day of a week", you mean Sunday; if not, you can adjust the code to mean Monday.  Hope this helps.