# HIVE SQL for Last X Weeks when it crosses over a year

Tags: sql, hive

I've searched but couldn't find a solution for **HIVE** and would appreciate any input.

I have a requirement to run data for the past 5 weeks. So I'm using

```
concat(year(current_date), weekofyear(current_date))-6
```

and

```
concat(year(current_date), weekofyear(current_date))-1
```

but of course when that reaches January, that won't work.

I initially had it like this because I am also querying last week's data, which would work in January since 201901 is still more than 201852. But if I do a between on the code above, in January 2019, I will not get the last 5 weeks of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't construct a date!  Just use `date_sub()`:

```
where datecol >= date_sub(current_date, 5 * 7)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a good suggestion, but if I understand correctly, this would only work if I run the query on a Monday, correct? I was using weekofyear so that any day of the week I can run the query.

Comment: So I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196651/how-to-get-the-date-of-the-first-day-of-a-week-given-a-time-stamp-in-hadoop-hive where it discusses how to get the first day of the week, I then took your snippet and then did a date add to get Monday which is my first day of the week.  (Surprisingly, cast'u' and the pmod function all return Sunday as first day of the week, while weekofyear returns Monday),`date_Add(date_sub(date_sub(current_date, 1 * 7),pmod(datediff(date_sub(current_date, 1 * 7),'1900-01-07'),7)),1)` I'm just still not sure what will happen in January.

Comment: @Gordons's code would work without any use `hive> select date_sub('2017-01-01', 5 * 7) from temp.emp limit 1;
OK
2016-11-27`

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I really appreciate it. Here is what I ended up doing: Getting the date for X weeks in the past then on top of that I needed to get the first day of the week,which gets me Sunday and I did a date add to get Monday. So the full statement to get last 5 weeks, or forward 5 weeks is: `round(avg(case when forecast.week_begin between
date_add(date_sub(current_Date,pmod(datediff(current_date,'1900-01-07'),7)),1)
and
date_add(date_sub(date_add(current_date, 4 * 7),pmod(datediff(date_add(current_date, 4 * 7),'1900-01-07'),7)),1) then sales_Forecast end)) `