# How to load data from hive table partitioned by month to a hive table partitioned by week

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two hive tables.

Source table is partitioned by month. So the partition column is like below.

```
event_column, partition_month
2021-10-25 00:48:36.0, 2020-10
2021-11-18 00:46:36.0, 2020-11
2021-12-20 00:42:34.0, 2020-12
```

Destination table is partitioned by week. Destination table has the partition column in below format

```
partition_week
2021-11-07
2021-11-14
2021-11-21
```

I want to load last 6 months data using the above two columns in where clause. Could anyone please help me.

Comment: how week should be represented?

Comment: It is represented in `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 1):

one option is to derive the partition week column based on the event_column.
`select next_day(date_sub(to_date('2021-11-18 00:46:36.0'),7),'SUN')`
which will give you 2021-11-14.You can then use this column while writing to the destination table.

Courtesy: [How to get the Date of the first day of a week given a time stamp in Hadoop Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196651/how-to-get-the-date-of-the-first-day-of-a-week-given-a-time-stamp-in-hadoop-hive) @Régis ARCHAMBAULT

Comment: This is good, thanks. Actually, I want to load 6 months old data  from the latest date present in the table. I can do it with a second query in the where clause. Is there any better way to do that.

Comment: I reckon this can be only achieved by first computing the 6th month old date from current date and then checking it falls in the partition week and month, if you want to make use of the other columns. As you said it will require a subquery. If I get something else I'll update